# Imacros JavaScript for loop not working with the desired condition

Tags: loops, imacros

hi i want to promt a message and ask for the value and start a loop from that number and end at 200 i used java scrpt in imacros with firefox

```
**

var macro;
    macro ="CODE:";
    macro +="VERSION BUILD=5301016 RECORDER=CR";
    macro +="TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=I ATTR=CLASS:fa<SP>fa-hand-o-up<SP>custom&&TXT:";
    macro +="WAIT SECONDS= 35";
    PROMPT "Please enter value" !n
    for (var i=n;i<200;i++)
    {
        iimset("i",i)
        iimPlay(macro)
    }
```

**

Answer (score 0):

I corrected your script. Try it like so:

```
var macro = "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=I ATTR=CLASS:fa<SP>fa-hand-o-up<SP>custom&&TXT:" + "\n";
macro +="WAIT SECONDS=35";

var n = parseInt(prompt("Please enter value"));
for (i = n; i <= 200; i++) {
    iimSet("i", i);
    iimPlayCode(macro);
}
```

Comment: thank for the help but it shows this TypeError: s is undefined (Error code: -1001)

Comment: can i call  macro from outside this script and send a value before calling

Comment: It seems that you use uncompatible versions of 'iMacros' extension and Firefox browser. What do you mean by "_... call macro from outside this script ..._" ?

Comment: can u help me out with perfect imacro and firefox versions

Comment: can i create a macro ex: a.iim and create a jscript i.e b.js and call a.iim from the b.js

Comment: and one more  i.e if i get a promt value 100 the i need to call 100.iim and if value is 101 then call 101.iim in the loop

Comment: (1) The most perfect 'iMacros' version is [8.9.7](http://wiki.imacros.net/Firefox#Version_History). (2) Read about the [JavaScript Scripting Interface](http://wiki.imacros.net/Firefox#Javascript_Scripting_Interface) and you will solve all your tasks.